# Vue table, list with multiple arrays with sub objects

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to ask. It is possible to simply render table with Object like this..

```html
list {
  Array[1] = [
    Object[0] = {
      name: "Hello world"
    }
  ],
  Array[2] = [
    Object[0] = {
      name: "Hello world"
    },
    Object[1] = {
      name: "Hello world"
    }
  ]
}
```

Somehow like this..

```
<tr v-for="(subrows, header) in list">{{ header }}</tr>
<tr v-for="subrow in subrows">{{ subrow }}<tr/>
```

the problem is that i cant simply create table with header rows and subrows..

i would be thankful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Can you edit your question so that it is clear how the data items in `list` correspond to `subrows` and `header`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have objects like `{arr1:[{name:"test11"},{age:11}],arr2:[{name:"test22"},{age:22}],arr3:[{name:"test33"},{age:33}]}` try below code

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    rows:{arr1:[{name:"test11"},{age:11}],arr2:[{name:"test22"},{age:22}],arr3:[{name:"test33"},{age:33}]}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <table border="1">
    <tr><th>Data for</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>
    <tr v-for="(index,row) in rows"><td>{{index}}</td><td>{{row[0].name}}</td><td>{{row[1].age}}</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

If your objects is different share exact object of sample of 2-3 elements of objects

Comment: But i have list where each array is header and in array each object is row :/
{arr1=[{name:1},{name:2}].arr2=[{name:3}]}

In laravel it would look something like this:
forach (items as x => y)
{{ $x->name }}
foreach (y as subitem)
{{ $subitem->.. }}
endforeach
endforeach

Comment: thx for helping, but how to get arr1,arr2.. as header of table and objects as rows

Comment: @nrkz : added key name in first column as well

Comment: Thanks man, but it is possible to add this key as a new tr like header?

Comment: yes its possible but not a good way because `arr1`,`arr2` are dynamic rows not columns.